# On connection change, incomple image is loaded by AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

During loading an image from url by AsyncTask, I turned internet connection off. Without any Exception, It assume incomplete image as an image. I wanna make it sure it has downloaded the whole image or not. How can I do.

```
URL url = new URL(p1[0]);
Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openStream());
saveImage(my_file,image);
return image;
```

Above is the code in AsyncTask class.

Answer (score 0):

Check with Picasso/ Glide.

Picasso you can try with

```
Picasso.with(context).load(p1[0]). //Your url
fit().centerCrop()
.placeholder(R.drawable.user_placeholder)
.error(R.drawable.user_placeholder_error)
.into("Your Image View");
```

Add the below dependency in app/build.gradle

```
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

Picasso download the complete image once and save in cache.

Glide you can try with

```
Glide.with(context)
.load(p1[0]) //your url
.placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
.error(R.drawable.imagenotfound)
.into("Your Image View");
```

Add the below dependency in app/build.gradle

```
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0'
```